# Ul lista com largura dinâmica independente dos itens

Tags: css

Tenho uma lista com vários blocos, gostaria que a largura da UL fosse dinâmica, se eu deletar uma `<li>` o tamanho da lista acompanhe sem quebrar os alinhamentos, ela precisa servir para 1 bloco, 3 blocos, 6 blocos.

```css
.bloco {
 background:#CCC;
 padding:0;
 min-height: 150px;
 max-width:600px;
 padding: 4px;
}

.item {
 display: inline-block;
 border: solid 1px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
 min-height: 100px;
 width: 24%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="bloco">
  <li class="item">
   1
  </li>
  <li class="item">
   2
  </li>
  <li class="item">
   3
  </li>
  <li class="item">
   4
  </li> 
  <li class="item">
   5
  </li>  
 </ul>
```

Comment: Existe um máximo de blocos?

Comment: Não podem haver vários blocos, mas existe um máximo da largura da UL, maximo 800 pixels, se tiver mais blocos mostra scroll.

Comment: Pode ser 600px, apena deve ter um tamanho máximo pra não deixar a tela com muitos itens.

Comment: O que você pediu agora não fez sentido, se eu tiver 1000 items todos vão ter 0.1% de largura e não vai ter scroll, ou tu tem um `min-width` para os itens?

Comment: Algumas considerações:

- A ul pode ter um máximo de 600px e tem uma barra de scroll
- Os blocos apenas duplicam dentro da UL

Comment: Samuel, à algum tempo eu fiz uma implementação semelhante, como você pode ver no seguinte [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TobyMosque/wamsc1ks/), certo que utilizei bastante JS.

Comment: Legal show de bola Tobias, aqui já está tudo certo, valeu abs!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cheguei no resultado igual da tabela porém que feito numa lista, ficou assim:

```css
ul {
 background:#CCC;
 padding:0;
 min-height: 70px;
 max-width:600px;
 padding: 4px;
 display: table-cell;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
 border: solid 1px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
 min-width:145px;   
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>a</li>
 <li>b</li>
 <li>c</li>
 <li>d</li>
 <li>e</li>
 <li>f</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Está errado e parece muito que você está enchendo de respostas na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Assim funciona diminuindo o tamanho até 6 itens:

```css
.bloco {
  background:#CCC;
  padding:0;
  min-height: 150px;
  max-width:600px;
  padding: 4px;
}

.item {
  transition: all 0.42s;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  float: left;
}

li:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
    width: 100%;
}

li:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ li {
    width: 50%;
}

li:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ li {
    width: 33.3333%;
}


li:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ li {
    width: 25%;
}

li:first-child:nth-last-child(5),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(5) ~ li {
    width: 20%;
}

li:first-child:nth-last-child(6),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(6) ~ li {
    width: 16.6666%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="bloco">
  <li class="item">
    1
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    2
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    3
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    4
  </li> 
  <li class="item">
    5
  </li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Flexbox

Utilizando a propriedade flexbox do css é possível manipular melhor a questão de fluidez que deseja entre os itens. Analise a diferença da class .content-wrap onde adiciono um novo parâmetro na propriedade flex-flow.

Sobre a questão cross-browser dessa propriedade, ela já está amplamente difundida nos browsers atuais. Só vai precisa analisar e alinhar com seu projeto se vai dar suporte para algum browser antigo que não suporte flex-box, assim você vai precisar analisar um fallback js para manipular seus elementos e manter a flexibilidade que deseja.

Tirando essa questão de compatibilidade, tudo perfect no CSS.

Aconselho também uma leitura sobre essa propriedade flex-box.
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Esse guide é super intuitivo também.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Espero ter conseguido ajudar, se precisar de ajuda só comentar.

```css
.box-container {
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.content-wrap {
 flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.box-item {
  background: tomato;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  flex: 1 auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>Primeira lista</h2>
<ul class="box-container">
  <li class="box-item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 5</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 6</li>
</ul>
<h2>Segunda lista</h2>
<ul class="box-container">
  <li class="box-item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 3</li>
</ul>

<h2>Terceira lista</h2>
<ul class="box-container">
  <li class="box-item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 5</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 6</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 7</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 8</li>
</ul>

<h2>Quarta lista com wrap</h2>
<ul class="box-container content-wrap">
  <li class="box-item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 5</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 6</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 7</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 8</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 9</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 10</li>
</ul>

<h2>Quinta lista com wrap</h2>
<ul class="box-container content-wrap">
  <li class="box-item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 5</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 6</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 7</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 8</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 9</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 12</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 13</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 14</li>
  <li class="box-item">Item 15</li>
</ul>
```